# $Scope.var1 variable is not available inside multiple forms under same controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller name say "CtrlABC", in which I have two forms namely, formA and formB. I want to access one $scoepe varialbe name $scope.var1's value in both the forms at the same time, I am able to access and change var1 value in first form but when trying to make change or access it in another form(which is below) then completely its not changing or accessing.
Here is my sample code.

```js
angular.module("MyApp").controller("test", ['$scope',function ($scope) {
$scope.StartDate;

$scope.generateChart=function(SelectedProduct){


//updated date should be here on click/submit of the form
console.log($scope.StartDate);


};

});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="test"><form name="A" ng-submit="generateChart(selectedProduct)" novalidate> <md-input-container><label>From</label>
                                        <md-datepicker required ng-model="StartDate"></md-datepicker>
                                    </md-input-container></form>
     <form name="B" ng-submit="generateChart(selectedProduct)" novalidate> <md-input-container><label>From</label>
                                        <md-datepicker required ng-model="StartDate"></md-datepicker>
                                    </md-input-container></form></div>
</div>
```

If I try to change the date from one to another the ng-modal variable is not updating itself.

Comment: post your controller and form1 and form2 code

Comment: I just updated above with an example.

Comment: **Sajeetharan**, anything else is required for testing.

Comment: yes what you have posted is not enough

Comment: Just updated my code with the controller.

Comment: **Sajeetharan**, is  there any update.

Comment: do you have team viewer/

Comment: No at this point I dont have

Comment: Sajeetharan, Any update?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130292/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-saleem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work according to your code, here is a demo. Probably you can check for other parts,

Make sure you are using the angular-material version v1.1 and above

```js
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module('app', ["ngMaterial"]);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.StartDate;
  $scope.generateChart = function(SelectedProduct) {
    //updated date should be here on click/submit of the form
    console.log($scope.StartDate);

  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <link data-require="angular-material@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.css" />
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-material@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" src="https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.1/angular-material.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-animate@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-aria@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular-aria.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body >
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <form name="A" ng-submit="generateChart(selectedProduct)" novalidate>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>From</label>
        <md-datepicker required ng-model="StartDate"></md-datepicker>
      </md-input-container>
    </form>
    <form name="B" ng-submit="generateChart(selectedProduct)" novalidate>
      <md-input-container>
        <label>From</label>
        <md-datepicker required ng-model="StartDate"></md-datepicker>
      </md-input-container>
    </form>
  </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: upvote means +1 there is an up arrow next to answer, it is different from markin as answer

Comment: **Sajeetharan**, I just check mine, but its having some strange problem. I mean I have problem with the bottom form its acting as its not inside the above wrapped controller .

Comment: come on chat here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130386/discussion-between-saleem-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: Are we talking in chat room?

Comment: **Sajeetharan**, Are you there to discuss?

Comment: **Sajeetharan**, Can we talk about the yesterday issue.